# Is @wordpress/env locked to node v14 or can I also use node v16?

Tags: plugin-development

Can I use node v16 with @wordpress/env? Docs seems to force you to install v14, but I need v16 for other projects.

Comment: "but I need v16 for other projects" - have you considered using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)? With it and a _.nvmrc_ I use various node versions for various projects on the same machine.